# Dynamically allocating a sum of 2d arrays in C

Tags: c, file, multidimensional-array, nested, dynamic-memory-allocation

For this exercise (where we must scan a txt file and return rows, columns, matrix 1 and matrix 2; then find the sum of matrix 1 and 2) there is extra credit for "using dynamic memory allocation," which is a few chapters ahead. Given my program below, how would I go about doing this? I know the 4 functions of dynamic memory allocation (malloc, calloc, free, and realloc), but not yet how to utilize them.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
    FILE *inFile;
    int i,j;
    int rows, cols;

    inFile = fopen ("Matrix.txt", "r");

    if (inFile == NULL)
    {
        printf("\n\nFile does not exist or cannot be opened.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    fscanf(inFile,"%d %d", &rows, &cols);

    int m1[rows][cols],m2[rows][cols],m3[rows][cols];

    /*Scan and store Matrix 1 and Matrix 2*/
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) 
    {
        for ( j = 0;j<cols;j++)
        {
            fscanf(inFile,"%d", &m1[i][j]);
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) 
    {
        for ( j = 0;j<cols;j++)
        {
            fscanf(inFile,"%d", &m2[i][j]);
        }
    }

    fclose(inFile);

    printf("\nThe sum of the two matrices:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            m3[i][j]=m1[i][j]+m2[i][j];
            printf("    %d", m3[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

}
```

Comment: The purpose of `malloc()`/`calloc()`, `realloc()` and `free()` is dynamic memory allocation, reallocation, and deallocation, respectively.    Which means you'll need to learn and use them.    And you'll need to learn about pointers.    If you don't understand those, there is no point giving "simple changes" to convert your program.

Comment: **I'd** go about this by inserting your title into *Google first*, adding `site:stackoverflow.com`, reading a couple of first links ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have your *"Matrix.txt"* file so I couldn't debug the code I wrote, but here it is anyway.

There's two answers bundled into one. The lazy way and the 2D array way.
I tend to prefer to handle my 2D arrays as 1D arrays in most cases since it's less code and fewer things to keep track of.

In order to test it, just comment or uncomment the `#define`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define IF_LAZY (1) // comment/uncomment this line if you like lazy solutions or not.

int main() {
    FILE *inFile;
    int i, j;
    int rows, cols;

    inFile = fopen("Matrix.txt", "r");

    if (inFile == NULL) {
        printf("\n\nFile does not exist or cannot be opened.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    fscanf(inFile, "%d %d", &rows, &cols);

#ifdef IF_LAZY

    /* Dynamic allocation using 1D arrays. */
    int* m1 = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * rows * cols);
    int* m2 = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * rows * cols);
    int* m3 = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * rows * cols);

#else

    /* Dynamic allocation using 2D arrays made out of pointers to pointers. */
    int** m1 = (int**) malloc(sizeof(int*) * rows);
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        m1[i] = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * cols);
    }

    int** m2 = (int**) malloc(sizeof(int*) * rows);
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        m2[i] = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * cols);
    }

    int** m3 = (int**) malloc(sizeof(int*) * rows);
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        m3[i] = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * cols);
    }

#endif

#ifdef IF_LAZY

    /*Scan and store Matrix 1 and Matrix 2*/
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            fscanf(inFile, "%d", &m1[i * cols + j]);
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            fscanf(inFile, "%d", &m2[i * cols + j]);
        }
    }

    fclose(inFile);

    printf("\nThe sum of the two matrices:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            m3[i * cols + j] = m1[i * cols + j] + m2[i * cols + j];
            printf("    %d", m3[i * cols + j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

#else
    /*Scan and store Matrix 1 and Matrix 2*/
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            fscanf(inFile, "%d", &m1[i][j]);
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            fscanf(inFile, "%d", &m2[i][j]);
        }
    }

    fclose(inFile);

    printf("\nThe sum of the two matrices:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            m3[i][j] = m1[i][j] + m2[i][j];
            printf("    %d", m3[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
#endif

}
```